# buildSessionFactory() fails - Could not initialize class HibernateUtil

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to use buildSessionFactory method but simply it doesn't work. It is very bizarre, since it was working for me with different example a few days ago. I google'd how to replace it with different solution but none worked so far, I am fairly new to Hibernate, so it's quite possible, that something else is crashing but my understanding of error messages tells me it must be it. This how I use it:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

but all error messages eventually point to:

```
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

and say:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.xxx.xxx.xxx.HibernateUtil (sorry, I had to hide names of those packages)

What can I use instead of this solution or how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation :

```
NoClassDefFoundError
```

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

It seems that your class `HibernateUtil` is not available at runtime. It has to be added into the classpath.

Comment: That helped, however I had to abandon this solution anyway... Thanks!